# (Simple) Digest function in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a 32 chars long text which I want to produce a 64-bit hash from. Security is not required, but it would be a huge plus.

My code will run on a embedded device which I can't load extensions. So the solution needs to use SQLite functions only.

If I were programming in C++, I'd be satisfied with something like:

```
char text[32];
int64 hash = 5381;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
  hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
}
```

How do I implement that in SQLite?

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: 3.x. I'll probably need to assume it has a given version and test.

Comment: The first stable 3.x version was released in 2004. What embedded platform is this? Can't you install 3.8.3?

Comment: Let's assume it has 3.8.3 (the device documentation does not mention the actual version). I'm going to try out a function available only in 3.8.3 to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., it is designed to be used within an application, where you can create user-defined functions.

If you really need to do this in SQL only, you can use a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE hash(id, h, rest) AS (
    SELECT id, 5381, text
    FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, (h * 33 + unicode(rest)) & 4294967295, substr(rest, 2)
    FROM hash
    WHERE rest != ''
)
SELECT id, h
FROM hash
WHERE rest = '';
```